# How to remove duplicate values from arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have these arrays i want to remove remove duplicate links from my array how can i do this please help

I have many links in my array first array have no key and others have key all links have unique ids i want to remove same id links and submit it into mysql. all work is done now i am stuck in this duplicate issue please kindly help me.

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => mainlink

        [apple] => Array
            (
                [0] => http://apple1.to/getac/fdjpkb9xdixq
                [1] => http://apple1.to/getac/fdjpkb9xdixq
                [2] => http://apple1.to/getac/fdjpkb9xdixq
                [3] => http://apple2.to/getac/fdjpkb9xdixq
                [4] => http://apple2.to/getac/fdjpkb9xdixq
                [5] => http://apple2.to/getac/fdjpkb9xdixq
            )

       [banana] => Array
           (
                [0] => http://banana1.to/getac/fdjpkb9xdixq
                [1] => http://banana2.to/getac/fdjpkb9xdixq
                [2] => http://banana1.to/getac/fdjpkb9xdixq
                [3] => http://banana2.to/getac/fdjpkb9xdixq
           )


    )
```

Thanks.

**I want this result:**

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => mainlink

        [apple] => Array
            (
                [0] => http://apple1.to/getac/fdjpkb9xdixq
                [3] => http://apple2.to/getac/fdjpkb9xdixq
            )

       [banana] => Array
           (
                [0] => http://banana1.to/getac/fdjpkb9xdixq
                [1] => http://banana2.to/getac/fdjpkb9xdixq
           )


    )
```

Comment: `$array['apple'] = array_unique($array['apple']); $array['banana'] = array_unique($array['banana']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just loop through your array with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and check if it is an array or not. If yes just return the unique array with [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), else just return the value.

```
<?php

    $unique = array_map(function($v){
        if(is_array($v))
            return array_unique($v);
        return $v;
    }, $array); 

    print_r($unique);

?>
```